# How can I pass http session to DeferredResult?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jackson, threadpool, lazy-evaluation

I have Spring MVC application with asynchronous endpoints:

```
@GetMapping
public DeferredResult<Collection<B>> get() {
    DeferredResult<Collection<B>> result = new DeferredResult<>();
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> result.setResult(service.getB()));
    return result;
}
```

I'm trying to serialize lazy object with [jackson-datatype-hibernate](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-hibernate):

```
@Entity
@Table
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
    private A a;

    public A getA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

But I'm getting:

```
Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: Could not write JSON: could not initialize proxy - no Session; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: could not initialize proxy - no Session (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.example.demo.B["a"])
```

Comment: The error is related to the `Hibernate Session` and not to the `HTTP Session`; basically you are trying to marhsal also the `A a` property of class `B` since you have a `Lazy` fetch strategy, you get the error

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Actually It works with Callable or CompletableFuture when I'm not trying to execute a task in new thread. I've added bean MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter with customized ObjectMapper using com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype.hibernate5.Hibernate5Module.

Comment: This is strange.. the error is pretty clear and the fetch strategy is always clear. Did you check that when it works all parameters are the same of the not working test?

Comment: @AngeloImmediata Yes, It definitely works with Callable or just Collection, even without Eager fetch type or JsonIgnore.

Comment: So the most probable reason is the one indicated in glitch answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the session refered to there is a Hibernate session not a HTTP session.

Your POJO (`B`) contains an attribute (`A a`) which is mapped with `FetchType.LAZY` so when that attribute is read the Hibernate session must be open and available in order to satisfy the lazy fetch.

I suspect you are opening a session-per-invocation-thread and since the response is handled on a different thread the Hibernate session is not available on the thread where `B` is serialised. You must pass some state (probably by creating an executable task/runner) to the thread on which the deferred result is created, you could extend this to include the currently open Hibernate session when you delegate (and remember to close this session when you have finished with that thread). Or, alternatively you could:

- Open a new Hibernate session on the thread on which the deferred result is created
- Change the FetchType so that it is no longer lazy.